# purrr::when() doesn't evaluate first condition

Tags: r, dplyr, case, purrr, .when

Apart from the more common `purrr::case_when` that elegantly performs a vectorised if-else statement, there is less known variant `purrr::when` which is non-vectorised yet still useful in many scenarios. Like `purrr::case_when`, the `purrr::when` syntax also contains condition-action pairs.

However, `purrr::when` doesn't seem to evaluate the first condition.
See here several cases with the example data from `purrr::case_when`.

```
x <- 35
purrr::when(
  x %% 35 == 0 ~ "fizz buzz",
  x %% 5 == 0 ~ "fizz",
  x %% 7 == 0 ~ "buzz",
  TRUE ~ "no buzz"
)
# should give "fizz buzz" but gives
"fizz"

purrr::when(
  x %% 5 == 0 ~ "fizz",
  x %% 7 == 0 ~ "buzz",
  TRUE ~ "no buzz"
)
# should give "fizz" but gives
"buzz"

purrr::when(
  x %% 7 == 0 ~ "buzz",
  TRUE ~ "no buzz"
)
# should give "buzz" but gives
"no buzz"
```

Side notes:

1. All conditions evaluate to TRUE.
2. The same behavior happens when TRUE is omitted in the last condition.
3. The same behavior happens when x is a vector (e.g. `x <- 1:100`).

#### Is this a bug??

It could be a bug because having only one condition throws this error message:

```
purrr::when(
  x %% 7 == 0 ~ "buzz"
)
Error: At least one matching condition is needed.

# However, case_when behaves as expected
dplyr::case_when(
  x %% 7 == 0 ~ "buzz"
)
"buzz"
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Ok this is the answer - thanks to [jennybc on github](https://github.com/tidyverse/purrr/issues/861#issuecomment-1116179527)

`purrr::when` requires the value as first argument!

```
x <- 35
purrr::when(
  x,
  x %% 7 == 0 ~ "buzz",
  TRUE ~ "no buzz"
)
```

I'm leaving the question and this answer here in case others might also oversee this, assuming the same arguments as for `dplyr::case_when`.